# c++: Swaping a map of maps

Tags: c++, std, swap

I have the following:

```
typedef std::map<int, std::map<std::string, std::string> > ComplexMap;
ComplexMap map_a;
ComplexMap map_b;
```

I want to swap the whole map_a to map_b. Is there a functional difference between the following two options:

```
// 1

ComplexMap::iterator end = map_a.end;
for (ComplexMap::iterator it = map_a.begin(); it != end; ++it)
{
    mam_b[it->first].swap(it->second);
}

// 2

map_b.swap(map_a);
```

Comment: the first one doesn't compile (typo!)

Comment: I don't think the first one does anything meaningful. do you have any constraints on those maps?

Comment: Assume `map_b` is empty and `map_a` is non-empty. Then the 1st code snippet does not generate correct result. After the code `map_a` is still non-empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first version has linear complexity (**O(N)**) and does not correctly swap the elements of the maps unless they have the same keys.

The second has constant complexity (**O(1)**) and correctly swaps the maps' elements. You should prefer the second.

Answer (score 0):

The second options should be more efficient than the first since map.swap will swap the whole content at once rather than iterating trough the whole content and moving it around. Also the first options is really confusing to understand.

Hope this helps,
Razvan.